# Getting type error that I cannot find the solution to

Tags: python, discord.py

Making a discord.py bot and im trying to add a menu to verify.

**Error:** TypeError: Client.event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

It's referring to my @bot.event line, and most places say having '()' is the problem but that is not the case here and I cannot get the bot to run without saying that same error in the event.

here is my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

activity = discord.Game(name="ValiantPS")
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)


class button_view(discord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Verify",
                       style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,
                       custom_id="Verify")
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                     button: discord.ui.Button):
        if type(bot.role) is not discord.Role:
            bot.role = interaction.guild.get_role(1077196175133900932)
        if bot.role not in interaction.user.roles:
            await interaction.user.add_roles(bot.role)
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"I have given you {bot.role.mention}!", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"You already have {bot.role.mention}!", ephemeral=True)


class bot(discord.Client):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False
        self.role = 1077196175133900932
        self.added = False


@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=908141823288045568),
              name='button',
              description='Launches role button')
async def button(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=button_view())


@bot.event
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    if not self.synced:
        self.synced = True
    if not self.added:
        self.add_view(button_view())
        self.added = True
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="ValiantPS"))
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please add full stack trace, especially with the line where it happens

Answer (score 0):

You have a class called `bot`, which is also the name of a variable. However, the class is defined later on, so it's overwriting the name. Hence, you're calling `SomeClass.event`, `SomeClass.run()`, etc. The `@event` decorators should be used on **instances** of classes.

Name your class something else so that you don't shadow that variable anymore. Class names should always be capitalized by convention, which would have prevented this issue from occuring in the first place.

Also, your `on_ready` is not inside of a class, so it shouldn't have `self` as the first argument. Events outside of your Bot/Client subclass can just use the `bot` variable to refer to the Client/Bot instance.